# SSRS 2016 Adding Columns or Unmerging Cells gives "Undocumented/RDL structure invalid" Error

Tags: reporting-services, bids, reportbuilder, ssrs-2016

Recently, I've been going through and converting/recreating a number of SSRS reports for the new 2016 version.  For the main part things are going well and the reports end up looking better, but I've run into one pretty glaring issue.  And that's an error with the text:

> Undocumented error.  The RDL structure of the tablix named
>   '%TABLIXNAME%' is invalid.

This error comes up when I try to insert a column within a group that spans two or more rows. I get the same error if I select "Split Cells" on a textbox spanning more than one row.  As seen here:

[image: Undocumented/RDL Error]

It looks like this is part of a larger underlying bug, as I found a different trigger that's easy to repro using a new report:

- In a blank report, create a matrix and skip the datasource.
- Insert a second detail row (inside group) at the bottom of the matrix.
- Insert a column (inside group) to the right of the first column.
- Unmerge the detail cells (works the first time), then merge them again.
- Unmerge a second time and get the Undocumented/RDL structure error.

Beyond that, it looks like someone else has triggered the same error when adding a 3rd level group to a tablix while the "Add Header" checkbox enabled: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d1792161-35ab-4b40-83a3-8014195ea91d/

But does anyone have any idea on a fix or workaround for the basic insertion issues described above?  For now I've taken to editing the RDL source so I can use the 2008 report builder to make changes but I am specifically looking for a solution that doesn't require such measures.

**Edit:**

And as far as I know, this problem is not specific to the report builder application as I've encountered identical behavior in VS 2015:

[image: VS2015 RDL Error]

Comment: You're not the only one. Same thing for us.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no answer to this - the only one is to use another VS version.

Comment: That's what I figured, thought I was hoping that someone figured out something clever.  I was also hoping that this wouldn't come up before a fix arrived.  But, of course, just today our Director of Marketing asked about adding breaking out sales groups in an existing report.  And trying to add a parent group runs straight into this error.

Comment: We do changes that break studio in Report Builder and then continue in studio.  That sucks but does not require to install one more visual studio only for editing reports

Comment: Forgive me for being unclear, but I actually encounter the same issue in both the Report Builder application and Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

if you insert a group above then split the cells it works you can then delete the row above

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this. You can create a child group, then swap the details over with the parent, so you have the grouping you need - bit clunky though